# How to match elements from arrays and only print matches?

Tags: python-2.7, arraylist

I have two lists, i am trying to match one item from the first list to another from the second list under a certain condition (for example if they share the same number in the same location). i wrote my code to match the first set ['A','B','C',4,'D'] and only print the set from list2 that has 4 in the same location. so basically my output would be:

```
 ['A','B','C',4,'D']
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

well i can't figure out how to print only the match

here is my code:

```
list1 = [['A','B','C',4,'D'],['A','B','C',9,'D'],['A','B','C',5,'D'],['A','B','C',6,'D'],['A','B','C',7,'D']]
list2 = [[1,2,3,2,5],[1,2,3,5,5],[1,2,3,3,5],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,1,5],[1,2,3,2,5]]

for var in list1:
    print var
    for i in range(0,len(list2)):
            for var1 in list2:
                if list1[0][3] == list2[i][3]:
                    print var1
```

Comment: I can see your shift button works in your code, but is it broken while you write elsewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program would become easier, if you used [izip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) of `itertools`. Assuming you just need to print the elements

```
from itertools import izip

list1 = [['A','B','C',4,'D'],['A','B','C',9,'D'],['A','B','C',5,'D'],['A','B','C',6,'D'],['A','B','C',7,'D']]
list2 = [[1,2,3,2,5],[1,2,3,5,5],[1,2,3,3,5],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,1,5],[1,2,3,2,5]]

for item1 in list1:
    for item2 in list2:
        for i,j in izip(item1, item2):
            if i==j:
                print i
```

By using izip two times, it would be much easier

```
from itertools import izip

list1 = [['A','B','C',4,'D'],['A','B','C',9,'D'],['A','B','C',5,'D'],['A','B','C',6,'D'],['A','B','C',7,'D']]
list2 = [[1,2,3,2,5],[1,2,3,5,5],[1,2,3,3,5],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,1,5],[1,2,3,2,5]]

for i in izip(list1,list2):
    for item1, item2 in izip(i[0],i[1]):
        if item1 == item2:
            print item1
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that's what I was looking for. I'm still very new to Python and I didn't know you could do a for loop with more than one variable before 'in'

Comment: You could do it by using izip in python2 and zip in python3. I highly recommend to read the documentation for both of them. Both are highly helpful when iterating over multiple lists

Answer (score 0):

Almost. I am not sure if that is what you wanted but the following code prints all pairs which have the same number in the 4th location of the array:

```
list1 = [['A','B','C',4,'D'],['A','B','C',9,'D'],['A','B','C',5,'D'],
['A','B','C',6,'D'],['A','B','C',7,'D']]
list2 = [[1,2,3,2,5],[1,2,3,5,5],[1,2,3,3,5],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,1,5],
[1,2,3,2,5]]

for t in list1:
   print t
   for b in list2:
      if t[3] == b[3]:
         print b
```

Output is:

> ['A', 'B', 'C', 4, 'D'] 
>   [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>   ['A', 'B', 'C', 9, 'D'] 
>   ['A', 'B', 'C', 5, 'D'] 
>   [1, 2, 3, 5, 5] 
>   ['A', 'B', 'C', 6, 'D'] 
>   ['A', 'B', 'C', 7, 'D']

Is that what you were looking for?